# Anyway to get Xcode (9.3) to remember login for more than a day?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

Xcode 9.3 keeps logging me out of the accounts. This is a bit annoying as I have a client who uses 2-form auth. It never used to log me out so often but since the upgrade seems to do so on a daily basis (for all my accounts). Any ideas to extended the remember time?

Comment: Check it how? Funny keychain should remember those PWs shouldn't it??

Comment: Apparently fixed in Xcode 9.3.1